# bash for finding line that contains string and including that as part of command

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a command that will print out three lines:

```
1-foo-1
1-bar-1
1-baz-1
```

I would like to include the result of this as part of a command where I search for the line that contains the string "bar" and then include that entire line as part of a command as follows:
`vi 1-bar-1`

I was wondering what the bash awk and/or grep combination would be for getting this. Thank you.

I had tried the following but I'm getting the entire output. For example, I'd have a file rows.txt with this content:

```
1-foo-1
1-bar-1
1-baz-1
```

and then I'd run `echo $(cat rows.txt | awk /^1-baz.*$/)` and I'd get `1-foo-1 1-bar-1 1-baz-1` as a result when I'm looking for just `1-baz-1`. Thank you.

Comment: Kindly do add your tried code in your question, it's highly encouraged, not my downvote BTW, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vi $(echo -e "1-foo-1\n1-bar-1\n1-baz-1\n" | grep bar | awk -F'-' '{print $2}')
```

The above script would equals `vi bar`

---

P.S.
`echo -e "1-foo-1\n1-bar-1\n1-baz-1\n"` is a demo to mimic your command output.

---

P.S.
You update the question... Now your goal becomes:

> I'm looking for just 1-baz-1.

Then, the solution would be just

```
cat rows.txt | grep baz
```

Answer (score 1):

*I search for the line that contains the string "bar"*:

A naive approach would be to just use

```
vi $(grep -F bar rows.txt)
```

However, you have to keep in mind a few things:

If your file contains several lines with *bar*, say

```
1-bar-1
2-bar-2
```

the editor will open both files. This may or may not what you want.

Another point to consider: If your file contains a line

```
1-foobar-1
```

this would be choosed as well. If you don't want this to happen, use

```
vi $(grep -Fw bar rows.txt)
```

The `-w` option requires that the pattern must be delimited by word boundaries.